# How to show only filtered data

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, filter

guys good morning. I want to display only filtered record in my table how this is possible my current code show the highlighted filtered record with other non filtered record. How this is possible.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
           foreach (DataGridViewRow r in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
               if (r.Cells[1].Value != null)
               {
                   if ((r.Cells[1].Value).ToString().StartsWith(this.textBox2.Text.Trim()))
                   {
                       this.dataGridView1.Rows[r.Index].Selected = true;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    } 
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: Your "filtering" only sets `Selected = true`. Sounds like you want something more like `Visible = true/false`

Comment: I want to show only filtered record. Currently it showing all records with filtered records highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Yorye Nathan's comment is correct

```
try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow r in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (r.Cells[0].Value != null)
                    {
                        if ((r.Cells[0].Value).ToString().StartsWith(this.textBox1.Text.Trim()) && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
                        { 
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[r.Index].Visible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[r.Index].Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Assuming input is something like

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Text", "Text");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("six");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("seven");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("eight");
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("nine");
```

Comment: This code is not working. Actually I already  binded a datagridview with database by frond end using datagridview task.

Comment: @user3471218 filter the results before the binding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my datagridview need a manual binding because of some tasks which is not possible in binding through coding.